# How to minimize a maximized window in osx yosemite?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

In my Mac OSX Yosemite whenever a window is maximized to full screen the yellow minimize button becomes disabled, along with top menu's *window/minimize* option and the associated *cmd+m* shortcut. Is there a way to directly minimize a full screen window in a single step without having to first shrink it down with the green button?

Answer (score 0):

No, because full-screening an app moves it to a different desktop. Use `Ctrl-Left` to get back to the main desktop, and `Ctrl-Right` to get back after that. If you're on a MacBook you can three-finger swipe left and right to accomplish this as well.